# After enabling of tls in our TYK server it runs out of filehandles and stop working

Tags: api-gateway, tyk

We have enabled tls in our on premise TYK dashboard and gateway after that it runs out of filehandles and stop working

> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status tyk-dashboard.service
>   tyk-dashboard.service - Tyk API Dashboard Loaded: loaded
>   (/usr/lib/systemd/system/tyk-dashboard.service; enabled; vendor
>   preset: disabled) Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-10-18
>   11:24:32 CEST; 3h 57min ago Main PID: 13062 (tyk-analytics) CGroup:
>   /system.slice/tyk-dashboard.service └─13062
>   /opt/tyk-dashboard/tyk-analytics --conf
>   /opt/tyk-dashboard/tyk_analytics.conf
>
> Oct 18 15:22:00 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk-analytics[13062]: 2018/10/18
>   15:22:00 http: Accept error: accept tcp [::]:3000: accept4: too many
>   open files; retrying in 1s Oct 18 15:22:01 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk
>   tyk-analytics[13062]: 2018/10/18 15:22:01 http: Accept error: accept
>   tcp [::]:3000: accept4: too many open files; retrying in 1s

our conf files looks like this

tyk.conf

```
{
  "listen_port": 8443,
  "node_secret": "secret",
  "secret": "secret",
  "template_path": "/opt/tyk-gateway/templates",
  "use_db_app_configs": true,
  "db_app_conf_options": {
    "connection_string": "https://localhost:3000",
    "node_is_segmented": false,
    "tags": []
  },
  "disable_dashboard_zeroconf": false,
  "app_path": "/opt/tyk-gateway/apps",
  "middleware_path": "/opt/tyk-gateway/middleware",
  "storage": {
    "type": "redis",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 6379,
    "username": "",
    "password": "",
    "database": 0,
    "optimisation_max_idle": 2000,
    "optimisation_max_active": 4000
  },
  "enable_analytics": true,
  "analytics_config": {
    "type": "",
    "ignored_ips": [],
    "enable_detailed_recording": true,
    "enable_geo_ip": false,
    "geo_ip_db_path": "",
    "normalise_urls": {
      "enabled": true,
      "normalise_uuids": true,
      "normalise_numbers": true,
      "custom_patterns": []
    }
  },
  "health_check": {
    "enable_health_checks": false,
    "health_check_value_timeouts": 60
  },
  "optimisations_use_async_session_write": true,
  "allow_master_keys": false,
  "policies": {
    "policy_source": "service",
    "policy_connection_string": "",
    "policy_record_name": "tyk_policies",
    "allow_explicit_policy_id": true
  },
  "hash_keys": true,
  "suppress_redis_signal_reload": false,
  "use_redis_log": true,
  "close_connections": true,
  "enable_non_transactional_rate_limiter": true,
  "enable_sentinel_rate_limiter": false,
  "experimental_process_org_off_thread": false,
  "local_session_cache": {
    "disable_cached_session_state": false
  },
  "http_server_options": {
    "enable_websockets": true,
    "use_ssl": true,
    "server_name": "localhost",
    "certificates": [
      {
        "domain_name": "*.ccta.dk",
        "cert_file": "/etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt",
        "key_file": "/etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key"

      }
    ],
       "ssl_insecure_skip_verify": false

  },
  "uptime_tests": {
    "disable": false,
    "config": {
      "enable_uptime_analytics": true,
      "failure_trigger_sample_size": 2,
      "time_wait": 10,
      "checker_pool_size": 50
    }
  },
  "hostname": "",
  "enable_custom_domains": true,
  "enable_jsvm": true,
  "oauth_redirect_uri_separator": ";",
  "coprocess_options": {
    "enable_coprocess": false,
    "coprocess_grpc_server": ""
  },
  "pid_file_location": "./tyk-gateway.pid",
  "allow_insecure_configs": true,
  "public_key_path": "",
  "close_idle_connections": false,
  "allow_remote_config": false,
  "enable_bundle_downloader": true,
  "bundle_base_url": "",
  "global_session_lifetime": 100,
  "force_global_session_lifetime": false,
  "max_idle_connections_per_host": 500
}
```

our tyk_analytics.conf

```
{
    "listen_port": 3000,
    "tyk_api_config": {
        "Host": "https://localhost",
        "Port": "8443",
        "Secret": "secret"
    },
    "mongo_url": "mongodb://127.0.0.1/tyk_analytics",
    "mongo_use_ssl": false,
    "mongo_ssl_insecure_skip_verify": false,
    "page_size": 10,
    "admin_secret": "secret",
    "shared_node_secret": "secret",
    "redis_port": 6379,
    "redis_host": "localhost",
    "redis_password": "",
    "enable_cluster": false,
    "redis_use_ssl": false,
    "redis_ssl_insecure_skip_verify": false,
    "force_api_defaults": false,
    "notify_on_change": true,
    "license_key": "secret",
    "redis_database": 0,
    "redis_hosts": null,
    "hash_keys": true,
    "email_backend": {
        "enable_email_notifications": false,
        "code": "",
        "settings": null,
        "default_from_email": "",
        "default_from_name": "",
        "dashboard_hostname": ""
    },
    "hide_listen_path": false,
    "sentry_code": "",
    "sentry_js_code": "",
    "use_sentry": false,
    "enable_master_keys": false,
    "enable_duplicate_slugs": true,
    "show_org_id": true,
    "host_config": {
        "enable_host_names": true,
        "disable_org_slug_prefix": true,
        "hostname": "localhost",
        "override_hostname": "localhost",
        "portal_domains": {},
        "portal_root_path": "/portal",
        "generate_secure_paths": false,
        "secure_cookies": false,
        "use_strict_hostmatch": false
    },
    "http_server_options": {
        "use_ssl": true,
        "servername": "localhost",
        "certificates": [
            {
                "domain_name": "*.ccta.dk",
                "cert_file": "/etc/pki/tls/certs/dev.api.data.ccta.dk.crt",
                "key_file": "/etc/pki/tls/private/dev.api.data.ccta.dk.key"
            }
        ],
        "min_version": 0
    },
    "security": {
        "allow_admin_reset_password": false,
        "login_failure_username_limit": 0,
        "login_failure_ip_limit": 0,
        "login_failure_expiration": 0,
        "audit_log_path": "/var/log/tyk/tyk-audit.log"
    },
    "ui": {
        "languages": {
            "Chinese": "cn",
            "English": "en",
            "French": "fr",
            "Korean": "ko"
        },
        "hide_help": false,
        "default_lang": "en",
        "login_page": {},
        "nav": {},
        "uptime": {},
        "portal_section": null,
        "designer": {},
        "dont_show_admin_sockets": false,
        "dont_allow_license_management": false,
        "dont_allow_license_management_view": false,
        "cloud": false
    },
    "home_dir": "/opt/tyk-dashboard",
    "identity_broker": {
        "enabled": false,
        "host": {
            "connection_string": "http://localhost:3010",
            "secret": "secret"
        }
    },
    "tagging_options": {
        "tag_all_apis_by_org": false
    },
    "use_sharded_analytics": false,
    "enable_aggregate_lookups": true,
    "enable_analytics_cache": false,
    "aggregate_lookup_cutoff": "01/07/2016",
    "maintenance_mode": false,
    "allow_explicit_policy_id": false,
    "private_key_path": "",
    "node_schema_path": "",
    "oauth_redirect_uri_separator": ";",
    "statsd_connection_string": "",
    "statsd_prefix": "",
    "disable_parallel_sessions": false,
    "dashboard_session_lifetime": 0,
    "alternative_dashboard_url": "",
    "sso_permission_defaults": null,
    "sso_default_group_id": "",
    "sso_custom_login_url": "",
    "sso_custom_portal_login_url": "",
    "notifications_listen_port": 5000,
    "portal_session_lifetime": 0,
    "enable_delete_key_by_hash": false
}
```

> cat /proc/981/limits Limit                     Soft Limit
>   Hard Limit           Units Max cpu time              unlimited
>   unlimited            seconds Max file size             unlimited
>   unlimited            bytes Max data size             unlimited
>   unlimited            bytes Max stack size            8388608
>   unlimited            bytes Max core file size        0
>   unlimited            bytes Max resident set          unlimited
>   unlimited            bytes Max processes             31191
>   31191                processes Max open files            1024
>   4096                 files Max locked memory         65536
>   65536                bytes Max address space         unlimited
>   unlimited            bytes Max file locks            unlimited
>   unlimited            locks Max pending signals       31191
>   31191                signals Max msgqueue size         819200
>   819200               bytes Max nice priority         0
>   0 Max realtime priority     0                    0 Max realtime
>   timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
>
> Number of file handles when it failed again with  Oct 23 13:04:34
>   sktudv01tyk01 tyk-analytics: 2018/10/23 13:04:34 http: Accept error:
>   accept tcp [::]:3000: accept4: too many open files; retrying in 1s

```
lsof | wc -l

31677


cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/tyk-gateway.service
[Unit]
Description=Tyk API Gateway

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
# Load env vars from /etc/default/ and /etc/sysconfig/ if they exist.
# Prefixing the path with '-' makes it try to load, but if the file doesn't
# exist, it continues onward.
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/tyk-gateway
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/tyk-gateway
ExecStart=/opt/tyk-gateway/tyk --conf /opt/tyk-gateway/tyk.conf
Restart=always
WorkingDirectory=/opt/tyk-gateway
RuntimeDirectory=tyk
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0770
LimitNOFILE=80000
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

OS settings ( centos )

```
  # /etc/security/limits.conf              

  *       hard    maxlogins       10       
  *          soft     nproc          80000 
  *          hard     nproc          80000 
  *          soft     nofile         80000 
  *          hard     nofile         80000 
  root       soft     nproc          80000 
  root       hard     nproc          80000 
  root       soft     nofile         80000 
  root       hard     nofile         80000
```

and in sysctl.conf i added

```
fs.file-max=80000
```

When i restart the tyk-dashboard i can login using https and my api's respond ok on https but after some minuttes it runs out of file handles

What do i need to change here, when starting dashboard alone everything is steady and running well, no errors in my log. But when i start the gateway my numbers of open files increase every second

gateway startup log

```
Oct 24 08:55:36 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:36" level=info msg="Setting up analytics normaliser"
Oct 24 08:55:36 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:36" level=info msg="PIDFile location set to: ./tyk-gateway.pid"
Oct 24 08:55:36 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:36" level=info msg="Initialising Tyk REST API Endpoints"
Oct 24 08:55:36 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:36" level=warning msg="Default secret `secret` should be changed for production."
Oct 24 08:55:36 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:36" level=warning msg="Default node_secret `secret` should be changed for production."
Oct 24 08:55:36 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:36" level=info msg="Redis connection pools are ready after number of retires" currRetry=0
Oct 24 08:55:36 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:36" level=info msg="Redis connection pools are ready"
Oct 24 08:55:36 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:36" level=info msg="--> Using SSL (https)"
Oct 24 08:55:36 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:36" level=info msg="Setting up Server"
Oct 24 08:55:36 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:36" level=info msg="Registering node."
Oct 24 08:55:36 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:36" level=error msg="Response failed with code 404; retrying in 5s"
Oct 24 08:55:37 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:37" level=warning msg="Insecure configuration detected (allowing)!"
Oct 24 08:55:37 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:37" level=info msg="Hostname set with dashboard zeroconf signal"
Oct 24 08:55:41 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:41" level=error msg="Response failed with code 404; retrying in 5s"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Node registered" id=10321add-ffb6-40c5-4692-c2035ee2760d
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Gateway started (v2.7.3)"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Initialising distributed rate limiter"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="--> Listening on address: (open interface)"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="--> Listening on port: 8443"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="--> PID: 10135"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Starting gateway rate limiter notifications..."
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Loading policies"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Using Policies from Dashboard Service"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Mutex lock acquired... calling"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Calling dashboard service for policy list"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Processing policy list"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Policies found (0 total):"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Detected 8 APIs"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Preparing new router"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Initialising Tyk REST API Endpoints"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Loading API configurations."
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Tracking hostname" api_name="Robotics - fast excel API #rpa" domain="(no host)"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Tracking hostname" api_name="gulapi_aarsopg #Gul" domain="(no host)"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Tracking hostname" api_name="rpaqlik_prod #rpa #prod" domain="(no host)"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Tracking hostname" api_name=awsvalues domain="(no host)"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Tracking hostname" api_name="rpaqlik #rpa" domain="(no host)"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Tracking hostname" api_name=postman domain="(no host)"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Tracking hostname" api_name=simons domain="(no host)"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Tracking hostname" api_name="eboks #eboks #java #dropwizard" domain="(no host)"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Loading API" api_name="eboks #eboks #java #dropwizard"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Loading API" api_name="Robotics - fast excel API #rpa"
Oct 24 08:55:46 sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk tyk[10135]: time="Oct 24 08:55:46" level=info msg="Loading API" api_name="gulapi_aarsopg #Gul"
lines 7537-7582/7616 100%
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SystemD, ensure that it does not mess with your file handler settings, by checking process limits like this: `cat /proc/<pid>/limits`. And if you find anomalies follow this guide https://tyk.io/docs/deploy-tyk-premise-production/#file-handles

Additionally your "db_app_conf_options.connection_string" is empty, instead it should point to the dashboard.

Also, you configured Gateway to use TLS, but in Dashboard config it still points to "http", and same for Gateway port.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, i have changed settings regarding to your recommendations, unfortunately i still get these errors.  I have reposted the actual newest conf files and some additional os conf in the question.

Comment: it also seems to open  both  ipv6 and ipv4 tyk-analy 1334 1381       tyk 1023u     IPv6             273038       0t0        TCP sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk:hbci->sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk:56906 (ESTABLISHED)

Comment: Have you verified that file handler limits for the dashboard were actually updated?

Also did you restarted both of the services?

Can you attach logs for both of them?

Comment: it runs on premise on one server so filehandle settings should be ok.

Comment: I cannot post the logs or upload them stackoverflow will not let me. Is there some way i can send of upload the files so you can see them ?

Comment: when starting dashboard alone everything is steady and running well, no errors in my log. But when i start the gateway my numbers of open files increase every second  i have added startup log for gateway service

Comment: testing with cat/proc/<pid>/limits, its ok but still it keeps creating filehandles.
0c5-4692-c2035ee2760d\",\"LoadPerSec\":1,\"Percentage\":0,\"TagHash\":\"\"} }"
Oct 24 13:09:50 sktudv01tyk01 tyk: time="Oct 24 13:09:50" level=debug msg="Received DRL data: {sktudv01tyk01.ccta.dk 10321add-ffb6-40c5-4692-c2035ee2760d 1 0 }"
Oct 24 13:09:50 sktudv01tyk01 tyk: time="Oct 24 13:09:50" level=debug msg="[Active Nodes]: 1 [Token Bucket Value]: 100 [Current Load p/s]: 1 [Current Load]: 0.000000"
level=debug msg="Getting exp for key: analytics-tyk-system-analytics"
♥